# How to view a cookie with requests

Tags: python

How would I grab the cookie that is generated when I do the following request?

```
res = requests.get('http://netflix.com', headers=headers)
# "Cookie": "b.voKfK9l.bmFuaWdhbnMgdXNlciBpZCAy=MTI4OTQ1NDMzMw; btpdb.voKfK9l.dGZjLjExMzIxMzQ=U0VTU0lPTg; btpdb.voKfK9l.dGZjLjE5MDM5Mzc=REFZUw; asearch=14333870421168910222; NSC_ED1-xxx=ffffffff09c8016b45525d5f4f58455e445a4a422d6a; NetflixCookies=persistent; dsrc=STRWEB_SIGNUP; custTrans=Y; isaffiliate=N; _ga=GA1.2.1091094536.1433192681; lastHitTime=1433387048919; nflxsid=10222.1433387048920; DVisitor=002~afd26f51-c034-49c2-b00d-242e471031d4~1433387042115~false~1433387048921~; dnmp="MDAxOjgwMDM1MzA1OjE0MzMzODcwNDg5MjE6Ojo="; obrd=true; btpdb.voKfK9l.dGZjLjE5MDM5NDI=REFZUw; btpdb.voKfK9l.dGZjLjYyODU4NA=REFZUw; RT=r%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.netflix.com%252FKids%26scrt%3D1433387209323; __utma=131134992.1091094536.1433192681.1433384047.1433386536.3; __utmc=131134992; __utmz=131134992.1433384047.2.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); VisitorId=002~TkZDRENILU1DLUFQWkhKSkY0MTZQR0ZXTFpHMjBHTlFMSjFOS1JMVQ~1433192615342~false~1433390331561~; nmp=MDAxOjUxNDAxOTE1OjE0MzMxOTI2ODczMTY6OnRya2lkPTIwMjY1MzpodHRwJTNBJTJGJTJGd3d3Lm5ldGZsaXguY29tJTJGV2lNb3ZpZSUyRjgwMDM4MTYyOg..; profilesNewSession=0; profilesNewUser=0; fbsr_163114453728333=YvlysQWMQZWSD5skRzBPg7E3V_w4vKyJaGbO26rKsNM.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImNvZGUiOiJBUUNxWmlSYU0tXzVqNDlfaGx3SWtuYXRwQ1JrS1RLRzJacmRpUHdCeDQ3Q0hLRzhJSjhfMTFuN1czbnNjcUd2WV9Dam5reTJ4WUJudEU5ZDFkY1hsbjBFT3AtbGpmVFBRZ3FhRmJwaUZvY0xRdExUYUZBMTNqWFVtWjJpUEE2dzhJSmN0cDdPdFI3S0c4anM3VGh4M0ZJRnhUdlF1aHI5ejVneWVhRHZoOE04S3NIVjR0dmdtVHJMUkwyQlhLaG5QcEhWRTl3Wk5ZTDdQVnBQeUhCTGdFb1hEMzdUVHJRSTBOS3ZfeWd0cXdheVV5TzIwLU5WQWY1ZVloS1JPUUNvRzgxSGdmMXNKQXpDeEZ0ZVgxNlRhbTR2cXJWUU5VY0VQN1I2OW9qdkJfNjhzS01PRjdFX3ZlbW1OUGVmdVZzOEJJRSIsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTQzMzM5MTMxNSwidXNlcl9pZCI6IjEwMTA1MTM4NDk3MzM2OTYzIn0; nflx-rgn=uw2|1433441095265; NetflixId=v%3D2%26mac%3DAQEAEAABABRDDyNgZbZrlM718-kHUjmj5XIDnsV2oJo.%26ch%3DAQEAEAABABSVdbzTOxNbZGJalzPJw2fWBwO98oA6adA.%26ct%3DBQAOAAEBEAtlUm3jkPkYMnC9Nr_oWKCCAK4_efWbf--3U8aL_zVKlh4xHBwZIYXVUhydKf9bHGGmU8Ai0iGRcNP63VWHCGgHxDZae7Iq6OhuCEKnGGaTetJVvafTZiIp8h5j8mPp2MnaAuSSNNRs8X8S5juml2jUYFSrGHXJHmYilFhh0Ogwid0pvykILuMAzE4FGGx3S1erHIwVHCE1FrcSDnYD9Wf1GPjWgVllNX7ch4Aqo9Xft8N11kFDjsCZFWHNv-fBpLKFwEirt9mfwQ5bEYylkwmqnEkYSo-eE28-9GESVepELdBajMwkDQk99DucN0g1yXS4ObKWpMdmUxM4oOTUvirmq8I4zIwMMgUYGu-CK83BpfLgUITDOdMEQzM9l1ENKJGlL_IsG0JbT7DYz4pqlG8eS1bUihwPAkRMPlxzw-oMeYacbvO2GoHQ9gk66THxxJ-Jht6yTVaoreOToI3_XazcFEq8nZDxl-W9TTWf1GEXYoyk-IvXGTbQwOo7CdyeOl96dj_2O7TmqrGJNl7kTgAckUXkvdFMSrEuR31twvP1zvl46mn3RIQqvj3gf_vkRW5h_f6xrjw7oLFJM2cRwGxgIxmsA4n7ai7PXlWAYM1ts-OxaIAX7Z6oq_3CUQf75ZCPic8RMYq9mlIdVWZWX13V-v2iaIZ769wbmiFXso7tJeDu5bEA2RC4NDJyX13-qCmh%26bt%3Ddbl; lhpuuid-wihome-11756="81bbb5a8-eebf-4dc2-881f-6f321622f596_ROOT:US-en-US"; JSESSIONID=BFCF0B4D38F3A9B61518CF88E4685651; tlr=US|1433441554843; cL=1433441632684%7C143344117037716678%7C143344117066172612%7C%7C18%7CIOS3P437CZFCTORM2IDRFPUL34; memclid=TkZDRENILU1DLUFQWkhKSkY0MTZQR0ZXTFpHMjBHTlFMSjFOS1JMVQ""",
```

Getting res.cookie seems a bit opaque. How would I grab the actual cookie value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies

```
r.cookies['example_cookie_name']
```

You could also use  the dict .get()

Answer (score 0):

Just by requests value.

```
requests.get(url).cookies
```